# Group Permission for Directory in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-permissions

I am using console application visual studio 2012 for make permission of group for directory but is getting error "Some or all identity references could not be translated."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateDirectory(@"C:\TestDirectory", @"NAVEEN\IIS_IUSRS");
        }
        public static void CreateDirectory(string DirectoryName, string UserAccount)
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(DirectoryName))Directory.CreateDirectory(DirectoryName);          
            AddUsersAndPermissions(DirectoryName, UserAccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
        }
        public static void AddUsersAndPermissions(string DirectoryName, string UserAccount, FileSystemRights UserRights, AccessControlType AccessType)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryName);
                DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
                dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new enter code hereFileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, UserRights, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessType));
                directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSecurity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your code as *text*, not as an image

Comment: Is your user account specified in the system exist? Looks like your identity specified is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the name of the PC from the group, you only need "IIS_USRS".

With this single change the below code runs without issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateDirectory(@"C:\TestDirectory", @"IIS_IUSRS");
        }
        public static void CreateDirectory(string DirectoryName, string UserAccount)
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(DirectoryName)) Directory.CreateDirectory(DirectoryName);
            AddUsersAndPermissions(DirectoryName, UserAccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
        }
        public static void AddUsersAndPermissions(string DirectoryName, string UserAccount, FileSystemRights UserRights, AccessControlType AccessType)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryName);
                DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
                dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, UserRights, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessType));
                directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSecurity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution of my issue.

I dont had Active Directory Group in my local.
*DirectorySecurity, AddAccessRule* will work only **Active Directory Group**, so
on client server I execute the console application from this sql side with this keyword: "**xp_cmdshell"**, Then a directory have created in **Active Directory Group** and that time not getting ant type of error.